# Calling non static method from static method

Tags: python, plone

I have a class and portal_type `Person` and there are 2 methods in it:

```
class Person(BaseContent):
    def print_all(self):
        catalog = getToolByName(self, "portal_catalog")
        results = catalog(portal_type = 'Person')
        final_result = ''
        for result in results:
            final_result += result.getObject().print_person()
        return final_result

    def print_person(self):
        return self.name
```

But I realised that `print_all` is not associated with any object so it should be static method. What I want to do is get all the instances of the person and call print_person(). But the problem is: what should I write in the catalog since there is no self object after I make the print_all method static method. For instance now I cannot write

```
catalog = getToolByName(self, "portal_catalog")
```

I want something like:

```
@staticmethod
def print_all():
    instance = Person()
    catalog = getToolByName(instance, "portal_catalog")
    .
    .
    .
```

But it is giving me `'invalid syntax'` error at `instance = Person()`! I hope my question is clear and any help will be appreciated!

Comment: In your example, print_all IS an instance method. If you want to make it static, you should use the @staticmethod annotation.

Comment: I have edited the question. The first code is what I have and the last one is what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `self` with `context`, like this:

```
# this is needed only if you don't have a context to pass
from zope.app.component import hooks

def print_all(context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = hooks.getSite()
    catalog = getToolByName(context, "portal_catalog")
    results = catalog(portal_type = 'Person')
    final_result = ''
    for result in results:
        final_result += result.getObject().print_person()
    return final_result
```

Comment: I am getting error in the getToolByName line it says 'raise AttributeError, name'

Comment: I am getting this hooks.getSite() as None when I call Person.print_all().

Comment: I've replaced `if not context` with `if context is None` as that test is a lot more precise *and* doesn't have any unexpected side effects and semantics.

Comment: @SadikshaGautam: Are you calling this outside of a request (so not through a HTTP call)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, I am in debugging mode and am just calling it from there. So, is there any other way how I can check this print_all method from the console that sets the value of context?

Comment: @SadikshaGautam: you have to set the site manually; `from zope.app.component.hooks import setSite` and `setSite(app.site)`. This is normally done with the traversal machinery.

Comment: yes thank you that solved the problem! What I did was set the site explicitly from the console and that seemed to do the trick! :)